# SQL SRVR 2016: Trouble joining to a nested select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join, outer-join

I'm working in a query window in SSMS.

Using 3 tables:

- WORK_ORDER wo

  - An order to fabricate a part
- OPERATION op

  - An operation in the fabrication of the part (laser, grinding, plating, etc.)
- PART pt

  - A unique record defining the part

My objective is to report on the status of an operation (say #3) (#total parts ordered, #completed parts), but additionally to include the number of parts that have completed the previous operation (#2) in the sequence and are ready for the process.  My solution was to use the LAG function, which works perfectly when the nested select statement below is run independently, but I get an avg of 4X duplication in my results, and my Completed_QTY_PREV_OP column is not displayed. I am aware that's because it's not in the parent select statement, but I wanted to correct the join first.  I'm guessing the two problems are related.

Footnote:  The WHERE contains a filter that you can ignore. The parent select statement works perfectly without the joined subquery.

Here's my sql:

```
SELECT  op.RESOURCE_ID, pt.USER_5 AS PRODUCT, wo.PART_ID, wo.TYPE, wo.BASE_ID, 
        wo.LOT_ID, wo.SPLIT_ID, wo.SUB_ID, op.SEQUENCE_NO, pt.DESCRIPTION, 
        wo.DESIRED_QTY, op.FULFILLED_QTY AS QTY_COMP, op.SERVICE_ID, op.DISPATCHED_QTY, wo.STATUS

FROM dbo.WORK_ORDER wo INNER JOIN
        dbo.OPERATION op ON wo.TYPE = op.WORKORDER_TYPE
        AND wo.BASE_ID = op.WORKORDER_BASE_ID 
        AND wo.LOT_ID = op.WORKORDER_LOT_ID
        AND wo.SPLIT_ID = op.WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID 
        AND wo.SUB_ID = op.WORKORDER_SUB_ID INNER JOIN
            dbo.PART pt ON wo.PART_ID = pt.ID

        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            --The nested select statement works by itself in a query window,
            --but the JOIN throws an error.
            (SELECT 
                pr.WORKORDER_TYPE, pr.WORKORDER_BASE_ID, pr.WORKORDER_LOT_ID, 
                pr.WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID, pr.WORKORDER_SUB_ID, pr.SEQUENCE_NO,
                LAG (COMPLETED_QTY, 1) OVER (ORDER BY pr.WORKORDER_TYPE, pr.WORKORDER_BASE_ID, 
                pr.WORKORDER_LOT_ID, pr.WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID, pr.WORKORDER_SUB_ID, pr.SEQUENCE_NO) AS COMP_QTY_PREV_OP
            FROM dbo.OPERATION AS pr) AS prev
            --End of nested select 

            ON
                op.WORKORDER_TYPE = prev.WORKORDER_TYPE AND
                op.WORKORDER_BASE_ID = prev.WORKORDER_BASE_ID AND
                op.WORKORDER_LOT_ID = prev.WORKORDER_LOT_ID AND
                op.WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID = prev.WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID AND
                op.WORKORDER_SUB_ID = prev.WORKORDER_SUB_ID

WHERE (NOT (op.SERVICE_ID IS NULL)) AND (wo.STATUS = N'R')
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. When you post a question because you get an error you should post the error message so others know what the problem is.

Comment: While we wait for the error message. I notice that you don't use any of the columns in your subquery in your main query. That won't affect whether it will run or not, but it seems odd. Can you also confirm that `COMPLETED_QTY` is a column in your `dbo.OPERATION` table?

Comment: I would also suggest changing your where predicates a little bit. The NOT function is not widely used, it is more common to use op.SERVICE_ID IS NOT NULL

Comment: Thanks, all.  I don't get an error message.  I get results, but they are multiples of the results without using the joined select statement.  As I said in my post, I'm aware that my desired column from the subquery is not in the parent select columns list, but the I think the problem is in the join. The parent query (including the WHERE clause) and the subquery both work perfectly when run independently.  The problem arises when they are joined.  Am I using the wrong kind of join?

Comment: Without a LOT more details posted this is impossible to answer. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a great place to start.

Comment: Or is the join in the wrong place?  The subquery should be joined to the OPERATION (op) table.

Comment: @JNevill: the COMPLETED_QTY is a column in OPERATION.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given enough information for a definitive answer, so instead I will give you an approach to debugging this.

You are getting unexpected rows as a result of a JOIN.  This means that your JOIN condition is not matching the two sides of the JOIN on a one-to-one basis.  There are multiple rows in the table being JOINed that meet the JOIN conditions.

To find these rows, temporarily change your SELECT list to `SELECT *`.  Do this both in the outer SELECT, and in the derived table.  Look through the columns being returned by the JOINed table, and find the values that you didn't expect to be returned.

Since the JOIN that causes the issue is the last one, they will be all the way to right of the result of a `SELECT *`.

Then add more conditions to the JOIN to eliminate the unwanted rows from the results.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the whole query by first creating a temp table filled by the previously nested SELECT, and then joining to it from the parent SELECT.

Works perfectly now.  Thanks for looking.

PS:  I apologize for the confusion about an error message.  I noticed after I posted that I had an old comment in the code regarding an error.  The error had been resolved before posting, but I neglected to remove the comment.